# Xcode Storyboard "View-As" does not list iPhone 11 Pro / XS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I am developing an app for my iPhone XS. I used to have "View-As" iPhone 11 Pro selected in the storyboard, as its the same screen size. Coming back after a few months, neither is listed in the "View-As" section anymore.

None of the available options offer the same screen size as my target device, what should I select to build the UI? The options are:

- iPhone 12 Pro Max
- iPhone 12 / 12 Pro
- iPhone 12 Mini
- iPhone 11 Pro Max
- iPhone 11
- Some iPhones with the home button and no notch
- Some iPads

Xcode 12.3, iOS target 14.3

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't be designing for specific devices. Use auto-layout with trait-variations to develop **Adaptive** designs that will look good across devices / size classes.

Comment: @Philip was I able to help you out with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use desired simulator. If you doesn't exist You can add new one
Click the device or simulators in just near the your project icon in Xcode and click the **Add additional Simulators**. section.

After follow ss steps as below

[image]